# Update One table Column with Values from Another table Having Similar

Tags: oracle

Hi Guys I have Two tables (MIGADM.CORPMISCELLANEOUSINFO and CRMUSER.PREFERENCES) and Each Has a field called PREFERENCE_ID and ORGKEY. I want to Update the Preference ID for MIGADM.CORPMISCELLANEOUSINFO with Preference_ID from CRMUSER.PREFERENCES for Each Corresponding ORGKEY. SO I wrote this Query;

```
update migadm.CORPMISCELLANEOUSINFO s set s.PREFERENCE_ID = (
select e.PREFERENCE_ID from crmuser.preferences e where s.ORGKEY = e.ORGKEY)
```

But I get:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

What Should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the columns you have selected are not unique enough to identify one row in your source table. Your first step would be to identify those columns.

To see the set of rows that have this problem, run this query.

```
select e.origkey, 
       count(*) 
  from crmuser.preferences e 
  group by e.origkey
  having count(*) > 1
```

eg : for origkey of 2, let's say there are two rows in the preferences table.

```
orig_key PREFERENCE_ID

2         202
2         201
```

Oracle is not sure which of these should be used to update the preference_id column in CORPMISCELLANEOUSINFO

Comment: You Are definitely Right. In the Second Table there was an ORGKEY that Had been repeated. Thank you. Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

identify the row where the subquery returns more than one row (You could use REJECT ERROR clause to do it for instance) or use the condition 'where rownum = 1'.